# Can't split at dot - Velocity

Tags: java, string, velocity, confluence

I would like to split a date at the dots between day.month.year. For example: 14.01.2015 to {14, 01, 2015} 
This is the code that i used: 
dates3.get(0) contains the String "14.01.2015" which i get from a textfield of the page.

```
##Splitting startingDate by point
#set($dates4 = [])
#foreach($id in $dates3.get(0).split(".")) ##BUG
#set($foo = $dates4.add($id))
$id<br>
#end
```

The array does not contain anything afterwards and when i print $id it just prints an empty line.

I figured that when i use - as a delimiter it works, but only for the month value. 
I have to put a - at the start and the end for it work (like this: "-14-01-2015-") and get the indexes 1-3 not 0-2, so that it works for all three values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`split()` wants a regular expression (regex). The dot in a regex stands for "any character", so you need to escape it:

```
.split("\.")
```

(for the generic reader: in other contexts the backslash must me escaped by another backslash in order to survive the syntax of strings: `.split("\\.")`)

Comment: Double slash did not work, but one slash worked for me, thanks! 
Dots do work now and i can get the parts using indexes 0-2, but somehow when i want to parse them to Integers using `#set($startYearInt = $startYearInt.parseInt("$dates4.get(3)"))` i still have to put a dot in front and at the end and use indexes 1-3 or it will give me an error. Do you know what could cause this?

Comment: Maybe you need to `trim()` the string, but I'm guessing. As for the double slash, I'll fix my answer, which was more a guess than an answer, since I don't know the tools you are using.

Comment: In Apache VLT template single backslash worked for me .split('\.')